# Fireboard forum :error message while use

Tags: joomla1.5

I am newbie to joomla. I have installed fireboard 1.0.4 package. while installation it doesn't give any error but while i am using in site it give following error

Table 'aks.jos_fb_whoisonline' doesn't exist SQL=INSERT INTO jos_fb_whoisonline (`userid` , `time`, `what`, `task`, `do`, `func`,`link`, `userip`, `user`) VALUES ('0', '1252517920', 'Forum Main','','','','/Joomla_1.5.12-Stable-Full_Package/index.php/forum', '127.0.0.1', '0')Serious db problem:Table 'aks.jos_fb_users' doesn't exist SQL=SELECT max(posts) from jos_fb_users

please help me out

Answer (score 0):

the answer to my question in
in administrator menu->componet->fireborad->control panel

there on the top there is a option of Clean Installation.Click on it and then use............
enjoy